# Express & jade rendering do not output correct utf-8 caracteres

Tags: express, utf-8, character-encoding, pug

I use express and jade to render html templates. To support translation and locales, i use an object for each locale, as i use french characters, there are many of special characters lice ç, é , è, à , but the html result replace all by �.

How to deal with utf-8 encoding ?

Comment: UTF-8 is the default character encoding for Node and Jade, so I wonder if your input data is actually valid UTF-8 to begin with. Can you show some code?

Comment: Thankyou @robertklep, i think that the fs.readFile is the problem, `fs.readFile(pathToFile, 'utf-8', function (err, string) {
  // the string here is mal formatted \n
   res.send(string);

})`

Comment: The problem is on file encoding and the need for additional workaround
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356713/node-js-readfile-error-with-utf8-encoded-file-on-windows

Comment: If a BOM is your issue, you could use [`strip-bom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-bom) on `string`.