# Syntax Error: Invalid or Unexpected Token when running a nodejs file using Visual Studio Code (Using powershell)

Tags: node.js, powershell

I've been trying to look for a solution but I can't seem to find one. I am a beginner to nodejs and basically I have created a new nodejs file called "app.js" inside of a directory called "HelloNode". When I use "node app.js" inside of powershell, the terminal tells me this:

[This is the image of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohs0b.png)

Code in VS Code:

```
var msg = "hello world";
console.log(msg);
```

Output in terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\yanab\HelloNode> node app.js
C:\Users\yanab\HelloNode\app.js:1
��v


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:791:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Solutions I have tried:

- Tried to change environment variable
- Used the nodejs correct version using nvm use 'version number'

Notes:

- Using a combination of Visual Studio Code and nvm
- After searching for a while it might have something to do with UTF-16 encoding and how it isn't in UTF-8 encoding but I may be wrong.

**Solution:**
Well I basically just made the file inside of vscode by right click -> new file and it worked. What I did before was use powershell and the command echo to make a new file. Don't understand what happened but making the file inside of vscode seems to be the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js readfile error with utf8 encoded file on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356713/node-js-readfile-error-with-utf8-encoded-file-on-windows)

Comment: @marsze do you mean typing out the code sample and the error message? Also I'm trying that link now

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation. It turns out the file was UCS-2 encoded. After converting it to UTF-8 using notepad ++, it started working fine.

In my case, the reason for the UCS-2 encoding was the way I was filling out the file:
echo 'console.log("Hollow world");' > test.js

Answer (score 0):

same problem here. I created file via powershell echo command. My solution is reopen my computer and create file without command line. :$

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that appears when there is some enexpected syntax when running javascript.

```
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
```

This second line says that this error appeared while compiling the code file. (even though javascript is not a compiled language). The same error appears for the following code(it wont even console log):

```
console.log('running code');
2q307qwekfjn;
```

So there is some error in the formatting of your file, some unexpected symbol(the ??v symbol) added by the ide or when saving etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with syntax, ’’ replace with '', usually few editors like the apple note program use ’ instead of ' and when you copy-paste, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved by updating the NodeJS version [source](https://replit.com/talk/ask/WHY-AM-I-GETTING-THIS-ERROR-AND-HOW-CAN-I-SOLVE-IT/146714)

First I ran "brew upgrade node", Then "nvm install --lts" and "nvm use --lts" and the error was gone

Comment: to what version?

Comment: I updated it to the latest version using "nvm install --lts" then "nvm use --lts"
I made sure to run "brew upgrade node" before hand, I will update my answer with the content of the comment

Comment: you can check what version you have now with `node --version`. I assume 18?

Comment: For some reason it says v14.19.0, I made sure to restart the terminal, not sure why but the app is running